# C++ 2D Array Initialization In Constructor - Program Runs Forever

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor

I have a small class that creates a 2D array based on a variable size.  The code I have for the class is as follows

```
class Treasure
{
        int** board;
        int size;

    public:
        Treasure(int boardSize)
        {
            board = new int* [boardSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
            {
                board[i] = new int[boardSize];
            }

            size = boardSize;
        }

        ~Treasure()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                delete [] board[i];
            }
            delete [] board;
            board = NULL;
            size = 0;
        }

        int get_value(int row, int col)
        {
            return board[row][col];
        }

        void set_value(int row, int col, int value)
        {
            board[row][col] = value;
        }


};
```

I wanted to test my `getter` so I just ran some simple code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    Treasure x1(2);
    cout << x1.get_value(0, 0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason when I ran the code the terminal window just had a flashing cursor and the CPU shot up to 100% and the memory usage went up to 1.5GB in a matter of seconds.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening?  It's been awhile since I've used `C++`, so I might just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `size` in your constructor before setting its value. So you will just have a garbage value there. Just move

```
size = boardSize;
```

up a few lines

Comment: Or better, use a constructor initializer list.

Comment: Yep, something simple haha.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In constructor, you didn't initialize "size" in the loop

> for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)

size here is undefined, and whatever garbage is here, it will be used in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Just in support of the already provided answers, your size variable has been declared but not initialised! In such a case, you're leaving it up to the compiler to assign a value to size which may or may not be 0.

Rule of thumb is to always initialise variables to a value i.e. `size = boardSize`, even pointers in which case set them to NULL. Setting the "size" to the your input should fix the problem :)